# Blender not responding when starting a Python script

Tags: python

I have a python script what works/runs most of the time but sometimes it makes Blender "Not Responding" (I closed the program after ~20 mins). What is weird that it looks like it's not even starting, because there is nothing on the Console though my script starts with a print:

```
import bpy
import json
import csv
import math
import struct
import imghdr
import os
import subprocess
from enum import Enum

class RuncodeEnum(Enum):
    GRAPHVIZ_FILES = 0
    WAVEFRONT_OBJECT = 1
    EXTRACT_COORDINATES = 2
    GENERATE_CONNNECTIONS = 3
    REINITIALIZE_SCENE = 4
    IMPORT_OBJ_FILE = 5
    TEST = 99

...

RUNCODE = RuncodeEnum.TEST

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting script, RUNCODE is '" + RUNCODE.name + "'...")
```

(Beside these there are a few constants and methods, likely it's not relevant.)

Any good advice what am I might doing wrong?

Comment: Bit hard to tell from that snippet.  Often caused by infinite loops `while True:` for instance.  Would also suggest not concatenating strings, by either using string formatting or for simple test prints:  `print("foo ", bar, 2000, "another string")`

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not a Python expert, but the program "should" start at that point, but there is nothing on the Console which implies the script didn't even start.

Comment: Why is that the starting point? what is `RUNCODE`

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. That's just an enum.

Comment: I see nothing in that code that will hang blender.  How are you running this script.  If run via "run script" operator, `__name__ == "__main__"` if autorun via registered script  `__name__` will be the module name, hence the if will never be true.

Comment: I run it via "run script" (Alt + P). Be aware that most of the time the code runs and works, no problem/issue whatsoever, and it takes like...0.2 seconds to run the script. Sometimes I can run the script 10-15 times without any problem, but once it didn't even start (made the program "Not Responding") for the first try...such a phenomenon for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had (have) to press Enter (any key?) in the Console window, but I don't know why...but it's a "solution" at least. If someone knows what can cause this, please feel free to write a post/comment.